# How to include js files in my EJS templates in node.js using express 3.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

All the examples I am seeing use the `app.dynamicHelpers` to provide a method for accessing my javascript files in my view templates. But in express 3.x there is no clear way to do this. The [migration docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) say "use middleware". I'm relatively new to the concept of 'middleware' and don't know how to implement this.

All I would like to know is the most elegant way to include javascript files in my view templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Middleware is the foundation to [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/), which Express is built upon. In short, it allows you to chain together multiple handlers of an incoming HTTP request and response. The argument you provide to each `app.use()` in your Express application is basically a "middleware" and is a callback with the following signature `function (request, response, next)`, where `next` is the next middleware callback to call in the chain. All the below are middleware (the last being an [error handler](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling) which has a 4 parameter signature):

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  // logic
  next();
});
```

In terms of the move from Express 2 to 3.x, the migration is specifically:

> `app.dynamicHelpers(`) (use middleware + [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals))

So, with a contrived example, where you may have previously had a helper function in an external `js` file and `require`d it for use in your `dynamicHelper`:

```
//helpers.js
exports.dynamicHelpers = {
  currentUser: function(req, res) {
    return req.user;
  }
};

// app.js
var helpers = require('./helpers').dynamicHelpers;

app.dynamicHelpers(helpers);
```

With a bit of reorganization you could now do something like:

```
//locals.js
exports.setLocals = function(req, res, next){ //<- middleware function
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  res.locals.otherVariable = ...;
  next();
}

//app.js
var locals = require('./locals').setLocals;
...
app.use(locals);
```

This is a good [blog](http://j-query.blogspot.ca/2012/02/expressjs-dynamic-helpers-vs-middleware.html) with a review of middleware vs. `dynamicHelpers` in pre-3.x Express, but the concepts are the same. The only difference being that `res.local(name, value)` used in the article is now [deprecated](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) for `res.locals.name = value` or `res.locals({ name: value })`